# can we lock few of installed iphone app or default app by our own app? is it posible to do?

Tags: iphone

i want to lock some of the installed app by my own app, please help me to do it.

hope some one may did already. its a kind of child lock.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to lock particular app in iphone by our own app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271873/how-to-lock-particular-app-in-iphone-by-our-own-app)

Comment: Not getting an answer is not a reason to repost the same question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271873/how-to-lock-particular-app-in-iphone-by-our-own-app

Answer (score 2):

Each app runs in its own sandbox and cannot affect other apps outside a few well-defined mechanisms, such as custom URLs. The capability is clearly there in the operating system, since you can restrict access to certain apps in the Settings app (Settings->General->Restrictions). There's no public API for doing that, though, and it's a good guess that Apple has locked that functionality down pretty tightly.

Comment: Thanks Caleb, i accept your answer. I came to know some undocumented apis are doing these kind of stuff, but apple never allow those kind of apis used apps in appstore. I need those kind of apis and its documents, could u know those kind of api?

Comment: Can you share some document link for apple never allow those kind of apis used apps in appstore?

I cannot find for those links

Answer (score 0):

Not Possible! 
Apple will not allow this app on iTunes

Comment: Hi Saurabh, i know apple never allow it, but i need to use private apis which are undocumented by apple. If u know about those kind of api then let me know. thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

No, It's not Possible, After spent too much time, Find the official doc provided by Apple.
Hope this may helps you:
https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/security/sec15bfe098e/web